# Word 2007: Tooltips showing footnotes no longer appear

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

On a normal installation of Word 2007, when you hover with the mouse over a footnote reference mark, a tooltip appears containing the text of the footnote.

Lately, this has stopped happening on my mom's computer. It used to work, it works fine on other computers.

The "Show Document Tooltips on Hover" checkbox in options *is* checked, and the mouse cursor does change (to an I-beam with a tiny note) when you hover over the reference mark, the but the tooltip itself is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Do tooltips appear anywhere on the system?  Can you use winspy++ http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy (or spy++ if your mom has Visual Studio on her system... hahaha!) to see if the window is actually appearing?

Answer (score 2):

Not a great answer, but I eventually solved this problem by running Office Setup, choosing "Repair," and then *rebooting the system*.

Comment: Holy Joel, it's Joel Spolsky are you for real.... A millionaire, a real millionaire right here.... LOL Not a great answer but it's the answer that solved your problem, +1 for being Joel Spolsky... I heard of this joke too, it goes a little something like: "What did Jeff Atwood say to Joel Spolsky when Joel fired him?" ... j/k

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this via the MS Word 2007 options panel, or with this line of VBA:

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayScreenTips = True
```